# How to get Array index in foreach

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop in php to iterate an associative array. Within the loop, instead of increamenting a variable I want to get numeric index of current element. Is it possible.

```
$arr = array('name'=>'My name','creditcard'=>'234343435355','ssn'=>1450);
foreach($arr as $person){
  // want index here
}
```

I usually do this to get index:

```
$arr = array('name'=>'My name','creditcard'=>'234343435355','ssn'=>1450);
    $counter =0;
    foreach($arr as $person){
      // do a stuff
$counter++;
    }
```

Comment: What use is a numeric index for an associative array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this syntax to `foreach` to access the key (as `$index`) and the value (as `$person`)

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $person) {
   echo "$index = $person";
}
```

This is explained [in the PHP `foreach` documentation.](http://us.php.net/manual/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need a *numeric* index inside *associative* array? Associative array maps arbitrary values to arbitrary values, like in your example, strings to strings and numbers:

```
$assoc = [
    'name'=>'My name',
    'creditcard'=>'234343435355',
    'ssn'=>1450
];
```

Numeric arrays map consecutive numbers to arbitrary values. In your example if we remove all string keys, numbering will be like this:

```
$numb = [
    0=>'My name',
    1=>'234343435355',
    2=>1450
];
```

In PHP you don't have to specify keys in this case, it generates them itself.
Now, to get keys in `foreach` statement, you use the following form, like @MichaelBerkowski already shown you:

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value)
```

If you iterate over numbered array, `$index` will have number values. If you iterate over assoc array, it'll have values of keys you specified.

Seriously, why I am even describing all that?! It's common knowledge straight from the manual!

Now, if you have an *associative* array with some arbitrary keys and you must know numbered position of the values and you don't care about keys, you can iterate over result of `array_values` on your array:

```
foreach (array_values($assoc) as $value) // etc
```

But if you *do* care about keys, you have to use additional counter, like you shown yourself:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($assoc as $key => $value)
{
    // do stuff with $key and $value
    ++$counter;
}
```

Or some screwed functional-style stuff with `array_reduce`, doesn't matter.

Comment: lol thank you @hijarian. It as asked 5 years ago. Now I have written books on PHP

Comment: @MarthaJames bwahaha, necroposting! :)